# Change logo with WPBakery Page Builder 5.4

Tags: php, wordpress, wpbakery

How change logo with  WPBakery Page Builder 5.4.

I not found that page in admin panel.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You change it in the theme options panel go to Header and change logo

Read more here: https://ueldo.com/documentation/how-to-change-logo-for-default-header-bar/